# Getting error during installation of visual studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, installation

I am using windows 7. Each time I am trying to install Visual studio Enterprise 2015, I am getting the following message:

[image]

How will I solve this?

Comment: As far as I know, there are some reasons that may be caused the Team Explore fatal error. To analysis the detail error message, you need to use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: Hi user76289, does your issue is solved or not? If not, you can shared the installation logs that can help us to analysis your issue, if this issue is fixed by yourself, could you share your solution as a reply with us? That can help other community members who have the same issue to search your solution.